# Javascript trigger function when iframe has loaded

Tags: javascript

I am creating an iFrame via an object instance, when the iFrame loads I need to trigger a method from the original object, and be able to retrieve the content of the iframe back in the object. At the moment "up" apparently does not exist.

```
function iFrame() {

var Id="1234";

var d = document.createElement('DIV');
d.innerHTML = '<iframe  id="'Id+'" name="'+Id+'" onload="up('+Id+');"></iframe>';

    document.body.appendChild(d);

    obj=this;

    var i = document.getElementById(this.frameId);
    i.up = (function(obj){obj.iFrameOnload()})(obj);

}

iFrame.prototype.iFrameOnload=function(id) {

d = document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document;


alert(d.body.innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? Up to which point does your code run so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting plain HTML inside of the div, you should actually create that iframe using DOM directly. This gives you several benefits:

```
var frame = document.createElement('iframe');

// set id and name attributes directly (although you don’t actually need them)
frame.id = '1234';
frame.name = '1234';

// set frame source (you probably want to set this)
frame.src = '';

// register event listener for the `load` event
frame.addEventListener('load', function () {
    // event handler here
    var d = this.contentWindow.document;
    alert(d.body.innerHTML);
}, false);

document.body.appendChild(frame);
```

As you can see, there is no need to ask the DOM again to get the iframe element via an ID or something. You created it directly after all, so you already have a reference to it.

Comment: I need the alert to occur within the original objects method iFrameOnload

Comment: @user1209203 There is no need for that extra function. The event handler itself (as an anonymous function in my example) does its job. You can give it a name if you like and then just call `frame.addEventListener('load', iframeOnLoadHandler, false);` instead where `iframeOnLoadHandler` is a function defined elsewhere.

Comment: Please show what you are trying to do. If you want to call the `iFrameOnload` which you added to your prototype (which you shouldn’t btw), then you could use `function () { this.iFrameOnload(); }` as the event handler. But your whole function does not really make sense: It shouldn’t be added to the prototype, and if you do it, you really shouldn’t look the object up in the document first. Just refer to it using `this`.

Comment: It's a method so that I can overwrite the method or extend for different uses of the object.

Comment: Why the downvote? Could you please explain yourself?

Answer (score 0):

your code there is a little messed up. allow me suggest something else:

include jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

and then:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    // create the iframe
    var url = 'http://www.google.com';
    var iframe_html = '<iframe src="' + url + '" id="iframe"></iframe>';
    $('body').append(iframe_html);

    // bind load event
    $('#iframe').load(function(){
        // on load code here
    });

});
</script>
```

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can create a global function up():

```
function up (iframe_element) {
    alert("In up() function");
}
```

And call it with the 'this' parameter

```
d.innerHTML = '<iframe  id="'Id+'" name="'+Id+'" onload="up(this);"></iframe>';
```

Full JS-code is in that case:

```
function up (iframe_element) {
    alert("In up() function");
}

function iFrame() {
    var Id="1234";

    var d = document.createElement('DIV');
    d.innerHTML = '<iframe  id="'Id+'" name="'+Id+'" onload="up(this);"></iframe>';

    document.body.appendChild(d);
}
```